# Counting the characters of dictionary values inside a dataframe column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, count

After downloading Facebook data, they provide json files with your post information. I read the **json** and **dataframe** with pandas. Now I want to count the characters of every post I made. The posts are in: df['data'] like: *[{'post': 'Happy bday Raul'}]*.

I want the output to be the count of characters of: "Happy bday Raul" which will be 15 in this case or 7 in the case of "Morning" from *[{'post': 'Morning'}]*.

```
df=pd.read_json('posts_1.json')
```

The columns are Date and Data with this format:

```
Date        Data
01-01-2020    *[{'post': 'Morning'}]*
10-03-2020    *[{'post': 'Happy bday Raul'}]*
17-03-2020    *[{'post': 'This lockdown is sad'}]*
```

I tried to count the characters of this *[{'post': 'Morning'}]* by doing this

```
df['count']=df['data'].str.len()
```

But it's not working as result in "1".

I need to extract the value of the dictionary and do the len to count the characters. The output will be:

```
Date        Data                                   COUNT 
01-01-2020    *[{'post': 'Morning'}]*               5
10-03-2020    *[{'post': 'Happy bday Raul'}]*       15
17-03-2020    *[{'post': 'This lockdown is sad'}]*  20
```

EDITED:

Used to_dict()

```
df11=df_post['data'].to_dict()
```

Output

```
{0: [{'post': 'Feliz cumpleaÃ±os Raul'}],
 1: [{'post': 'Muchas felicidades Tere!!! Espero que todo vaya genial y siga aÃºn mejor! Un beso desde la Escandinavia profunda'}],
 2: [{'post': 'Hola!\nUna investigadora vendrÃ¡ a finales de mayo, Â¿Alguien tiene una habitaciÃ³n libre en su piso para ella? Many Thanks!'}],
 3: [{'post': 'Â¿CÃ³mo va todo? Se que muchos estÃ¡is o estÃ¡bais por Galicia :D\n\nOs recuerdo, el proceso de MatriculaciÃ³n tiene unos plazos concretos: desde el lunes 13 febrero hasta el viernes 24 de febrero.'}]
}
```

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: You cannot have JSON inside your DF, as there is no Python JSON data type.  What you have there is a basic dictionary.  Extract the value from that entry and use `len`.  Since you didn't post code, we can't fix your specific problem.

Comment: @Prune I just added the code and what I expect as output

Comment: can you do `df.to_dict()` of your input dataframe after reading it in and post the output?

Comment: @DavidErickson I added by editing in the post. Still don't know how to go into the value of every line and count the len.

Comment: @pabloFerro see reproducible answer.

Comment: I'll wait for the MRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of the `post` key for each row using list comprehension and count the length with `str.len()`:

In one line of code, it would look like this:

```
df[1] = pd.Series([x['post'] for x in df[0]]).str.len()
```

This would also work, but I think it would be slower to execute:

```
df[1] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x['post']).str.len()
```

Full reproducible code below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [{'post': 'Feliz cumpleaÃ±os Raul'}],
 1: [{'post': 'Muchas felicidades Tere!!! Espero que todo vaya genial y siga aÃºn mejor! Un beso desde la Escandinavia profunda'}],
 2: [{'post': 'Hola!\nUna investigadora vendrÃ¡ a finales de mayo, Â¿Alguien tiene una habitaciÃ³n libre en su piso para ella? Many Thanks!'}],
 3: [{'post': 'Â¿CÃ³mo va todo? Se que muchos estÃ¡is o estÃ¡bais por Galicia :D\n\nOs recuerdo, el proceso de MatriculaciÃ³n tiene unos plazos concretos: desde el lunes 13 febrero hasta el viernes 24 de febrero.'}]
})
df = df.T
df[1] = [x['post'] for x in df[0]]
df[2] = df[1].str.len()
df
Out[1]: 
                                                   0  \
0                 {'post': 'Feliz cumpleaÃ±os Raul'}   
1  {'post': 'Muchas felicidades Tere!!! Espero qu...   
2  {'post': 'Hola!
Una investigadora vendrÃ¡ a fi...   
3  {'post': 'Â¿CÃ³mo va todo? Se que muchos estÃ¡...   

                                                   1    2  
0                             Feliz cumpleaÃ±os Raul   22  
1  Muchas felicidades Tere!!! Espero que todo vay...  112  
2  Hola!\nUna investigadora vendrÃ¡ a finales de ...  123  
3  Â¿CÃ³mo va todo? Se que muchos estÃ¡is o estÃ¡...  195
```